# Make tinymce in umbraco accept html 5 standards

Tags: html, tinymce, umbraco

I'm trying to publish a piece of html to umbraco.

I managed to setup tinymce to accept all the html tags, however, there is still some wrong transformations being done.

When I publish this piece of html:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <a href="" class="card-link">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h2 class="card-link-title">Currencies</h2>
          <i class="card-link-icon icon icon-money-currencies"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

It is transformed to:

```
 <div class="col-md-4">     
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h2 class="card-link-title">Currencies</h2>
          <i class="card-link-icon icon icon-money-currencies"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The a tag is removed. According to new html5 standards, div under a tag is valid (http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes), so I'm wondering if there's a way to make tinymce in umbraco accept the piece of html as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the javascript in `umbraco/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js`. (The file mentioned by Jannik Anker in the other answer is a legacy version of tinymce, no longer used)

Look for a line

```
n("a","href target rel media hreflang type",u)
```

and try amending it to

```
n("a","href target rel media hreflang type",u,"div")
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache after editing so the updated file is used.

Comment: This was a hidden one! Thank you so much!

Comment: I found the unminified source here http://archive.tinymce.com/download/older.php and worked backwards. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

A quick look inside /umbraco_client/tinymce3/tiny_mce_src.js reveals a function named getHTML5() where these rules seem to be defined. In my 7.4.0 test site I'd change line 2507 to

```
'a[A|href|target|ping|rel|media|type][B][div]' +
```

BUT that's not really doing anything, even if you make the same change in /umbraco_client/tinymce3/tiny_mce.js, because the RTE editor is using a different JS entirely, namely /umbraco/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js in which I cannot find that same function :-s

I don't have time for much further investigation, but maybe this can get you a little bit further?

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to look at